# Garbage collection - orphaned LinkedList links

Tags: java, garbage-collection, linked-list

Suppose you have references `A -> B -> C -> D`. When you delete the reference to `B` from `A`, you're left with an orphaned chain of Objects `B -> C -> D`.

Will `C` and `D` be garbage collected even though there's no way to get to them (since there's no reference to `B`)?

I imagine the GC is smart about this and will resolve any such dependencies.

However, I took a look into the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.clear%28%29) for the `LinkedList` class and found something contrary to this belief. I noticed that when a list is `clear()`ed, all of the references to each link are explicitly set to `null`, thus making it an `O(n)` operation. Is there any reason/benefit for doing so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That does look a bit peculiar.  Maybe the reason that it is explicitly dismantling the list is so that the list is cleared for existing iterators and sublists as well as the parent list.

It is certainly NOT done to make the garbage collection faster.  A garbage collector doesn't traverse the references in an unreachable object, so nulling them won't make any difference.

**UPDATE**

A more recent version of the method has these comments:

```
// Clearing all of the links between nodes is "unnecessary", but:
// - helps a generational GC if the discarded nodes inhabit
//   more than one generation
// - is sure to free memory even if there is a reachable Iterator
```

So, it appears that there is an benefit for the GC, at least in some cases.

Suppose that a `Node` in an older generation contains a reference to an object (e.g. a `Node` or an element) in a younger generation.  That reference becomes a "root" when collecting of the younger generation, causing the young generation object to be retained, even if the old generation `Node` is unreachable.  This state continues until the older generation is collected.  Old generations are collected infrequently.

If you traverse the list and dismantle it, the variable containing the old -> new reference is assigned a `null`.  The write-barrier for that assignment causes (immediately or at GC time) the original reference to no longer be a "root".  Thus, the object in the younger generation can now be collected, and it doesn't end up "tenured" to an older generation (which brings forward the time when that generation needs to be collected).

Presumably, the GC benefits outweigh the cost of unpicking the list ... either on average, or in cases where the costs are disastrous.

For more information, refer to "Garbage Collection algorithms for dynamic memory management" by Jones and Lins.  It is in chapter 7.5 in my (first edition) copy.

---

Generally speaking, it is better to throw a `Collection` object away and start again than it is to clear it for reuse.

Comment: Ah yes, this is exactly correct! `Iterator`s and `ListIterator`s both contain references to the internal nodes. `SubList`s however do not.

Comment: For the record, the source now explicitly documents that it can benefit a generational GC.

Comment: @shmosel That *what* can benefit a generational GC?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede What we're discussing... the dismantling of `LinkedList`.

Comment: @shmosel To be clear, are you contradicting or supporting the statement that it's better to throw the whole list away?  I looked at the `LinkedList` source on GrepCode and didn't find what you were referring to.  (I know, this thread is very old...)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Neither. I'm saying there's some GC benefit in disconnecting each node when `clear()` is invoked, rather than just discarding the endpoints. You can see the updated source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.clear%28%29).

Comment: @shmosel Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, C and D will be garbage collected, assuming that B is the only thing that referenced them.  This is because they are not reachable from the graph to the root objects of the application object graph.

I imagine the reason for marking each link to `null` in the `LinkedList` implementation is to prevent a memory leak.  It is possible for something outside of the `LinkedList` to grab a hold of the head node.  If this were to happen, it would keep all the other nodes alive even after the `LinkedList` has been cleared.

Comment: Also, `null`ing them out allows the garbage collector to clear them more efficiently, without walking the object graph, correct?

Comment: When a garbage collection is triggered, the whole object graph will be traversed and the objects will be marked as 'in use'.  So, yes, I suppose it will make the traversal shorter.

Comment: Actually, only the reachable object graph is traversed by a typical garbage collector.  The links from B to C and C to D won't be traversed, so nulling them doesn't help performance.

Comment: @Stephen C: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear.  I was talking about the reachable object graph.  I was also assuming nulling out values that were previously reachable will make the traversal shorter.  I guess I am just misunderstanding everyone today...

Comment: That would be true except there's no way to get an external reference to the head node as it's `private` and there are no getters for it.