# Implementation of removeFirst() method in SLinkedList in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, adt

I got the following code from one book for implementing a singly linked list. And I don't understand some lines of code in the `removeFirst()` method, which removes the first node from the LinkedList.

```
class ListNode{
    private String element;
    private ListNode next;

    public ListNode(){
        element = null;
        next = null;
    } 
    public ListNode(String s, ListNode n){
        element = s;
        next = n;
    }
    //Access method
    public String getElement(){
        return element;
    }
    public ListNode getNext(){
        return next;
    }
    //Modify method
    public void setNext(ListNode n){
        next = n;
    }
}

public String removeFirst(){
    if(head == null)
        return null;
    else{
        ListNode temp = head;
        head = head.getNext();
        temp.setNext(null);   //Which I don't understand, is it necessary?
        size --;
        return temp.getElement();
    }
}
```

It seems that the statement `temp.setNext(null);` can be omitted. So why it is here, does it has anything to do with the garbage colletion in java. Since I am new to Java, any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935579/garbage-collection-orphaned-linkedlist-links

Comment: Because the list is doubly linked list. I guess head.previous should be null after the first element is removed.

Comment: The list is a singly linked list.

Comment: As the answer in @Thinkingcaps comment says: Iterators keep references to the ListNodes.

Comment: In response to comment of @keuleJ I have editted my answer. The line is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the entire implementation of the linked list, which you have not included in your question. However if it is possible for objects to hold a reference to a node even after if has been removed from the list, then the line is necessary.

Suppose we have a long chain of nodes `A -> B -> C -> ...`. Suppose all of these nodes have been removed from the list, but that we still hold onto a reference to `A`. If all the nodes still held a reference to the next, this would prevent all of the nodes from being garbage collected. Simply setting the next node to be `null` ensures that only `A` cannot be garbage collected.

It is likely that implementations of a linked list *do* mean that references to nodes can be retained. For example, many implementations of `Iterator` hold a reference to the current node.

Consider this code:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if ("foo".equals(i.next())) {
        i.remove();
        break;
    }
}
// lots more code
```

This code searches a list for the first occurrence of the `String` `"foo"`. If it is found, it removes the `"foo"` from the list and breaks from the loop. The trouble with this is that the `Iterator` `i` is still in scope for the remaining code and still holds a reference to a node. This node may be in the middle of the list if the `break` occurred. Without setting `next` to be `null`, this would prevent all subsequent nodes from being garbage collected while `i` is still in scope, even if the list is cleared.

Note that you should generally make an iterator local to a loop anyway, like this

```
for (Iterator<String> i = list.iterator();;i.hasNext())
```

Comment: suppose we had a single linked list A->B->C->D. Now we had a local variable defined in removeFirst()method reference to A,  and A still holds a reference to B, without being set to null. And we set the head which is an instance variable to the B.  So after the call  of the removeFirst() method, will the A be collected by the GC? How dose that work?

Comment: Ask yourself, "Can I write code to access A ?" if the answer is No,  it will be collected . In your example here, as soon as you exit `removeFirst()` method , A will be unreachable and hence collected. So the answer is `No` you don't need to set next to null,  if you are just extracting the value of removed node and nothing more !

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose, single linked list of nodes is : `A --> B --> C --> D` with head node as A. Now, lets go though your **removeFirst()** method. When it get called,  `if(head == null)` condition doesnt satisfy because our head node "A" is not NULL.  Then it execute else statement,
`temp = head` //take head reference into temporary variable
`head = head.getNext();` //As we want to delete first Node which is head so we are setting head to next node (i.e. head --> next) which is Node **"B"**
Now, to delete A (first Node) we need to break connection between A (which is previous head)--> B (current head) and that will done by
`temp.setNext(null);` //so out linked list became A   B-->C-->D
and then as one node is deleted so in next statement it decreases size of link by `size--`.

I think we also set the temp reference to NULL as `temp=NULL` to make deleted node eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Even you don't do: temp.setNext(null) --- [temp] will be collected by GC soon