# Custom Linked List implementation garbage collection

Tags: java, memory-leaks

Given a custom linked list implementation in java (from Cracking The Coding Interview)

```
public class Node {
    public Node next = null;
    public int data;

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
    }

    protected void appendToTail(int d){
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
    }
}
```

If we were to create a linked list out of this and then iterate through it without a temporary variable to point to the original head, i.e.

```
Node list = new Node(5);
list.appendToTail(2);
list.appendToTail(4);
```

Gives us a list

```
5 -> 2 -> 4
```

What would happen if I issued

```
list = list.next;
```

Would this be a memory leak as it would be in C? Or would Java garbage collect?

Comment: Look at [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935579/garbage-collection-orphaned-linkedlist-links)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: No, there will not be a memory leak.

If you are advancing the pointer to point to the second node, that means a reference to the head is lost. This is assuming you have no other references to the head.

Without any reference pointing to it, this object will be marked for garbage collection.

Comment: That's awesome to know, makes things feel a lot safer. Thanks!